# Livecode - Can't add android SDK

Tags: android, livecode

I tried to set up Livecode 6.6.2 and I have no success adding `Android SDK` for mobile support.

I downloaded the latest ADT plugin and add it but it always fail.

See this error:
[image]

On my research, it might now work on Android tools revision 23. So I downloaded the old sdk from here: http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r20.0.3-macosx.zip

I added also Android 2.2. See this image:
[image]

I don't know what I am missing here, please help.

Comment: Hi JunM, The following video gives you step by step instructions on how to set up LiveCode for Android Development. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=83qrKr9bR3M . Please give it a watch and keep us posted on how you get on

Comment: @Niel Roger Thanks for the link. I'll check that out later. Though this is already working on my end. I think I have read it from the livecode forums somewhere and I already forgot how I did it :)